# CODEIGNITER: Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, image-resizing, gd2

Gd2 is also enabled. Tried many ways... Don't know what's wrong

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: getimagesize(): Read error!
>   Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
>   Line Number: 1651
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ciflix/application/controllers/Admin.php Line: 52
>   Function: library File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ciflix/index.php Line: 315
>
> Function: require_once
>
> ---
>
> The provided image is not valid.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

```
$config['upload_path'] = $path;
$config['allowed_types'] = $allowed_types;
$config['max_size'] = 15000;
$config['max_width'] = 1024;
$config['max_height'] = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('file_error', $this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect('admin/create_blog');
}else{
    $data = $this->upload->data('userfile');
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path.$data['userfile'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = 200;
    $config['height'] = 200;
    $config['new_image'] = $path.$data['userfile'];
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Working";
        exit();
    }

    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
}
```

Comment: You should enable `GD` extension from `php.ini`

Comment: did you restart apache2?

Comment: Did but didn't work                     extension=php_gd2.dll

Comment: yes. restarted.

Comment: is it okie now?

Comment: Nope... Also I am using ubuntu @Shanukk

Comment: @vijay-sharma . Can u help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the GD extension. If it is already installed, edit your `php.ini` to enable it (delete the `;` to not make it a comment ).

If it isn't installed, try this:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

EDIT:

I just noticed you mentioned a .dll. That's for Windows! Comment iut out, enable the `extension gd.so`, and restart the server, see if that helps!

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned a `.dll`. That's for Windows! Comment iut out, enable the extension that ends in `.so`, and restart the server, see if that helps!

Comment: Look for `;extension=gd.so` and remove the `;`

Comment: I can't find gd.so line in php.ini file. There are several thing which ends with .so extension. Couldn't know which to uncomment @delboy1978uk

Comment: do a `phpinfo(); exit;` at the top of a page, and then CTRL-F to find `GD`, and `.ini`. It's installed if it has it's own section, however it could come from another ini file, so search ini and it will show all the ini files loaded. If it's not in any of them, try the `apt-get` command to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

or

```
apt-get install --reinstall php5.0-gd
```

then restart apache

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

OR enable the library GD2 from `php.ini` file remove semicolon from `;extension=php_gd2.dll`

Check GD is enabled or not using the following command

```
$ php -i | grep -i --color gd
```

You can also test using php code.create a php file using the following code and run and check the GD extension is enabled or not

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: New Error afer removing semicolon:-                                                            
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_gd2.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Comment: @filxy after remove semicolon you should restart apache

Answer (score 0):

During my project I faced similar problem. This [link](http://philhawthorne.com/codeigniters-image-library/) help me to solve it.

Replace

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

with

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
// Set your config up
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do your manipulation
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a local server like **XAMPP**, you probably have **Port 80** being used by another application.

[image: XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.4]